# Why does ?: in regular expressions not work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a word with a space in the beginning but without a space in the output using ?:

[image: issue]

Comment: Use a capture group instead `\s(j\w+)` and get the group 1 value. Note to not post images only in your question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, and where should I put my images then?

Comment: You can add an image for clarity, but in this case you can also add your code with your output.

Comment: I acknowledged how ?: works, not how I imagined, it just has an interesting name "non-capturing group"

Comment: The non capture group here is unnecessary, as the group itself has no real purpose. The capture group on the other hand `(j\w+)` captures the value in group 1, which you access in the code. Note that the lookbehind [has this support](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the non-capturing group (`?:`), you can use the "match prefix but exclude" group (`?<=`).

```
let g = /(?<=\s)j\w+/i;
console.log("Here is John".match(g));
```